# how to resize a image propertly? image cropping when switching to mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the main banner image on my website [here click here](https://parlous-morals.000webhostapp.com/)

feel free to use right click inspect element then check the "toggle device toolbar" or use ctrl+shift+m ....

[image]

as you will see the main image is cropping itself in mobile mode instead of resizing:

[image]

the code, html:

```
<div class="block-slideshow__slide-image block-slideshow__slide-image--desktop image" style="background-image: url('images/slides/slide-1-full.jpg')"></div>
                                        <div class="block-slideshow__slide-image block-slideshow__slide-image--mobile image" style="background-image: url('images/slides/slide-1-mobile.jpg')"></div>
```

the css:

```
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    .block-slideshow--layout--full .block-slideshow__slide-image--desktop {
        background-position: -70px top
    }

    .block-slideshow--layout--full .block-slideshow__slide-content {
        left: 56px
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    .block-slideshow--layout--full .block-slideshow__slide-image--desktop {
        background-position: -190px top
    }
    
    
@media (max-width:767px) {

    .block-slideshow__body,
    .block-slideshow__slide {
        height: 395px
    }

    .block-slideshow__slide-image--mobile {
        background-position: top;
        display: block
}
}

.image{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

[css online](https://parlous-morals.000webhostapp.com/css/style.css)

what i need is the image to stretch, not to crop, and since i am a newbie i do not know how to...

tried this approach:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp

but does not work and i do not know what to do...

[image]

[image]

thank you in foward

Comment: `background-size:contain;`

Comment: As @Breezer said you can use `background-size:contain;` but you should adjust `block-slideshow__slide` height

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<img src="'images/slides/slide-1-full.jpg">
```

**CSS**

```
img{ aspect-ratio: 16/9 }
```

*maybe this is what you are looking for*

**I recommend you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKO1ktPQByk) at 6:10**